# Sending logs to email using Spring boot

Tags: spring, email, spring-boot, logback, amazon-ses

I'm trying to figure out how to configure my Spring boot project, to send log messages to an email, but had no success yet. No email sent, no visible error.

My logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>

    <appender name="mail" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
        <smtpHost>email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com</smtpHost>
        <from>dev@example.com</from>
        <to>dev@example.com</to>
        <subject>Something went wrong</subject>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout"/>

        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="mail"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

My application.yaml:

```
spring:
  mail:
    host: email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
    protocol: smtps
    username: ***
    password: ***
    port: 465
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          socketFactory:
            port: 465
            class: javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
            fallback: false
          ssl.enable: true
        transport.protocol: smtps
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a different way to send log messages to email in Spring Boot?

Comment: I think you're trying to configure different things. In one side, you've got the logback appender, which needs some credentials to log in the mail server. On the other side, you're configuring the spring mail module, which is valid to send mails, but logback knows nothing about it....

Comment: I'd recommend logging to a localhost MTA which then relays to SES

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan localhost MTA relay is not an option, as the app will run on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, which has no local MTA by default. (I know, there is a way...)

Comment: @XtremeBiker that was it, thanks, I had to add credentials to logback.xml. If you convert your comment to an answer, I'm happy to accept that.

Comment: @endrec done. Glad that helped you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're configuring the Spring mail module in your application.yaml instead of providing logback appender with the necessary data. You might need credentials for authentication in the SMTP server:

```
<appender name="mail" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
    <smtpHost>email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com</smtpHost>
    <username>user</username>
    <password>user</password>
    <from>dev@example.com</from>
    <to>dev@example.com</to>
    <subject>Something went wrong</subject>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout"/>

    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>DEBUG</level>
    </filter>
</appender>
```

**See also:**

- [Logback SMTPAppender documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SMTPAppender)
- [Configure Spring Mail when using Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-email.html)

Answer (score 3):

Pls use this (PS: Dont try to load property from properties file to logback as its not visible while startup & if still wish to set property then provide them as JVM argument as its visible to logback) :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <appender name="dbgMailer" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
      <smtpHost>email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com</smtpHost>
      <smtpPort>25</smtpPort>
      <from>dev@example.com</from>
      <to>dev@example.com</to>
      <subjectStr>Something went wrong</subjectStr>
      <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout"/>
      <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
          <level>DEBUG</level>
      </filter>
  </appender>
    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="dbgMailer" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This answer is misleading as now you can add <property resource="application.properties" /> and your application properties will be visible